# False positive security alert from Google?

Tags: authentication, account-security, google

I just had this security alert about one of my Google accounts:

- Device : Unknown device
- Time : 25 minutes ago
- Place : United States
- IP Address : 2a00:1450:4864:20::51b

> Someone just used your password to try to connect to your account from an application not belonging to Google, we have blocked this person.

This alert arrived 30 minutes after I had made some security modifications and checks on my account. Moreover, I verified this IPV6 address, and it belongs to Google (I am using a VPN). Is it a false positive?

Answer (score 1):

What did the security alert say? For example, did it say there was some suspicious account activity for this account?

Sometimes, Google sends these security alert messages so that you, the account owner, can help to verify if it was legitimate activity (in this case, you made some security related modifications, so it sounds like it was all legitimate?) or not. If it was legitimate, there is no need to worry.

If it was not legitimate, you can then take action like changing like your password for that account.

**Updated based on the additional information provided**

I think Google doesn't know that your two Google accounts are both belonging to you. So if you set up Google account A to access the email of Google account B, then I guess the first times it tries to retrieve the email, Google would alert the account holder of account B, in they were not aware of it. (maybe their password was stolen and now the attacker is trying to access their email without their knowledge)

Comment: Hello, i found why! It's Gmail trying to get to emails of this account from another account, I don't understand why Google can't detect this: "Auth error. The e-mails coming from this account where last retrieved at 08:31". Thanks for the help. I have added the details in the question about the reason (in quote).

Comment: Glad to hear you found it! Was it maybe an old version of gmail? I've experienced problems with old android phones which cannot update their Android OS any more, and sometimes they cannot securely connect to gmail servers to retrieve gmail, etc.

Comment: But it's the web version of Gmail not my phone. That's why I don't understand why Google can't detect that it comes from a service it owns.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the culprit:

It's Gmail trying to get to emails of this account from my main account:

[image]

I don't understand why Google can't detect this. People who had the same problem: [Gmail Account Password Compromised Twice In Two Weeks](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/176620/86376)

I think Google should provide an option to avoid considering himself (Gmail) as a security threat.

Comment: It may not be the Google considers Gmail a security threat, but access to the email of the other account, for the first time, from your main account, may be what caused the flag. I updated my answer according to what you said.

Comment: OH, I see, they wrote "from an application not belonging to Google, we have blocked this person." which would be over-reacting and wrong (as Gmail belongs to Google). ok, yes, it seems like a bug or other problem with their algorithm.